# None difference for Python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, nonetype

I've read a lot about Python versions differences but never met those

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None.__eq__("abc")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__eq__'
```

and

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None.__eq__("abc")
NotImplemented
```

I found it already being in Python 3.2

```
Python 3.2.6 (default, Jan 18 2016, 19:21:14) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> None.__eq__("abc")
NotImplemented
```

What I wan't to know if it is told somewhere in docs or somewhere. Didn't find anything [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html). Any sources?

Comment: Did you check the official documentation of None https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `NotImplemented` is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) in the python 3 docs. It looks like python 2 None type doesn't have the `__eq__` method at all

Comment: @farch, I get returnet `NotImplemented` (which is not even an Exception) with Python 3.8. That's what I am asking about

Comment: @byxor, yes. That's what it actually is. But I didn't find that change being stated in change logs. My questiong is about whether it's stated anywhere

Comment: @byxor, my guess is that Python2.7's `NoneType` is old-style class, which has no dunder methods, whereas Python3's `NoneType` is new-style class which returns NotImplemented. Also it's now good to know that not only `0, None, False, ""` evaluate to False when used with if, but also NotImplemented